# Generar tabla HTML de 12 x 8 y los datos mostrarlos en orden por columnas

Tags: php, html, tablas

[image: Captura de pantalla del resultado esperado]

Generar una tabla HTML como la imagen con PHP.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora? ¿Podrías compartir algo de código?